# EV3 Education does not recognize NXT ultrasonic sensor

Tags: ev3, education, sensor-ultrasonic

How do I get the NXT ultrasonic sensor to work in the *Education EV3 Classroom* application?

- OK: I have connected a **NXT ultrasonic sensor** to the input port 1 of an EV3 control brick.
- OK: For testing, one motor is connected to port B.
- OK: In the EV3's "port view", I see that port 1 is reported as `1:NXT-US-CM`.
- OK: In the EV3's "port view", I see that port B is reported as `B:L-MOTOR-DEG`.
- OK: A simple program in the *EV3 Home Edition* works: the motor turns according to the sensor output.
- **Problem:** A simple program in the *Education EV3 Classroom* application does nothing. The application shows only the motor is connected. The ultrasonic sensor is not shown.

*EV3 Home Edition:*
[image]

*Education EV3 Classroom* application:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

*EV3 Classroom* only supports LEGO EV3 sensors. It does not work with NXT or 3rd-party sensors.

Comment: Drat. Thank you. Can you provide a source?